# Django Warning - RemovedInDjango110Warning: render() must be called with a dict, not a Context

Tags: django, django-views

I upgraded my django project from 1.8.4 to 1.9.7 and now I get the following warning

> **RemovedInDjango110Warning: render() must be called with a dict, not a Context.
>     return HttpResponse(t.render(c))**

my views generally look like this

```
def my_view(request):

    .
    .
    .

    context_data = "context data to render"

    t = loader.get_template('maps/my_template.html')
    c = Context(context_data)
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

any suggestions how to fix this?

---

**update**

based on the approved answer my code will become the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):

    .
    .
    .

    context_data = "context data to render"

    return render(request, 'maps/my_template.html', dict(context_data))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`django.shortcuts.render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function has been a utility method for a while now that includes the request and passes the context data in a dictionary, so you can change most of your code to reflect the new method

```
context_data = "context data to render"

t = loader.get_template('maps/my_template.html')
c = Context(context_data)
return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

would turn into

```
render(request, 'maps/my_template.html', {'item1': value })
```

---

The actual error however is stating that `render` now just needs a dictionary, and not a context object. so it would be `t.render({'item1': value})`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `context_data = "context data to render"` into `context_data["context_data"] = "context data to render"`.

Goal being to change `context_data` into a dict.